# How to make my entire Flutter app only able to register single touches?

Tags: flutter, dart, draggable

I am making an app and I want the entire app to only ever be able to receive single touches. For example, if the app has 2 draggable containers, I want only one container to be draggable because I want the whole app to only register 1 touch at a time. Is this possible?

Here is some code (simplified), could somebody show me how to do it with this simple sample code? So I can figure out how to do it with my more complex code? Thanks!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyTest extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyTestState createState() => _MyTestState();
}

class _MyTestState extends State<MyTest> {

  int myTestInt = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('test'),
            Text('test'),
            Text('$myTestInt'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my attempt at your solution (it's probably wrong, sorry, I'm pretty new at this):

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'my_widget.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  bool isPressed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.indigoAccent,
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          InkWell(
            onLongPress: () {
              if (isPressed == false) {
                setState(() {
                  isPressed = true;
                });
              }
            },
            child:  Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                child: Center(
                  child:
                  DragTarget<dynamic>(builder: (context, accepted, rejected) {
                    return Draggable(
                      maxSimultaneousDrags: 1,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                        color: Colors.pink,
                      ),
                      feedback: Container(
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                        color: Colors.pink,
                      ),
                      childWhenDragging: Container(
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                        color: Colors.yellowAccent,
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          InkWell(
            onLongPress: () {
              if (isPressed == false) {
                setState(() {
                  isPressed = true;
                });
              }
            },
            child:  Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
                child: Center(
                  child:
                  DragTarget<dynamic>(builder: (context, accepted, rejected) {
                    return Draggable(
                      maxSimultaneousDrags: 1,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                        color: Colors.pink,
                      ),
                      feedback: Container(
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                        color: Colors.pink,
                      ),
                      childWhenDragging: Container(
                        height: 50,
                        width: 50,
                        color: Colors.yellowAccent,
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

ANOTHER UPDATE OF NEW CODE: 
main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterdragtest/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays ([]);
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

home_screen.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'my_widget.dart';
import 'my_class.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

void reload() {
  print('Reload');
  setState(() {});
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.indigoAccent,
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          MyWidget(id: 1, reload: reload,),
          MyWidget(id: 2, reload: reload,),
          MyWidget(id: 3, reload: reload,),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my_widget.dart: ( i knew it's super bad code but its just testing )

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutterdragtest/my_class.dart';

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {

  final int id;

  final Function reload;

  MyWidget({@required this.id, @required this.reload});

  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {

  bool whichAbsorb() {
    switch (widget.id) {
      case 1: {
        return CircleData.dk1;
      }
      break;
      case 2: {
        return CircleData.dk2;
      }
      break;
      case 3: {
        return CircleData.dk3;
      }
      break;
    }
  }

  void setAbsorb() {
    switch (widget.id) {
      case 1: {
        setState(() {
          CircleData.dk1 = false;
          CircleData.dk2 = true;
          CircleData.dk3 = true;
        });
      }
      break;
      case 2: {
        setState(() {
          CircleData.dk1 = true;
          CircleData.dk2 = false;
          CircleData.dk3 = true;
        });
      }
      break;
      case 3: {
        setState(() {
          CircleData.dk1 = true;
          CircleData.dk2 = true;
          CircleData.dk3 = false;
        });
      }
      break;
    }
  }

  void clearAbsorb() {
    setState(() {
      CircleData.dk1 = false;
      CircleData.dk2 = false;
      CircleData.dk3 = false;
    });
  }

  bool blockCheck() {
    switch (widget.id) {
      case 1: {
        if (CircleData.dk1 == false) {
          return true;
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }
      }
      break;
      case 2: {
        if (CircleData.dk2 == false) {
          return true;
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }
      }
      break;
      case 3: {
        if (CircleData.dk3 == false) {
          return true;
        }
        else {
          return false;
        }
      }
      break;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AbsorbPointer(
      absorbing: whichAbsorb(),
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(40),
        child: Center(
          child: DragTarget<dynamic>(
              builder: (context, accepted, rejected){
                if (blockCheck()) {
                  return GestureDetector(
                    onTapDown: (_) {
                      setAbsorb(); widget.reload();
                    },
                    child: Draggable(
                      onDragStarted: () {setAbsorb(); widget.reload();},
                      onDragCompleted: () {clearAbsorb(); widget.reload();},
                      onDraggableCanceled: (e, q) {clearAbsorb(); widget.reload();},
                      maxSimultaneousDrags: 1,
                      child: Container(height: 50, width: 50, color: Colors.pink,),
                      feedback: Container(height: 50, width: 50, color: Colors.pink,),
                      childWhenDragging: Container(height: 50, width: 50, color: Colors.yellowAccent,),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                else {
                  return Container(height: 50, width: 50, color: Colors.green,);
                }
              }
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my_class.dart:

```
class CircleData {

  static int num;

  static bool dk1 = false;
  static bool dk2 = false;
  static bool dk3 = false;

}
```

Comment: Sorry @Sniperduel17 I don't know how to solve your problem.

Comment: @Uni shoot its an app breaking bug. Could I just make the whole app ever only register 1 tap at a time? Anyway thanks for the help

Comment: I think you either have to wrap everything that will be touched with what I wrote below or you can use absorbpointer widget to make it work.

Comment: @Uni so I totally redid my code to work for absorbpointer. It works WAY better than I had it. Previously I could drag one around for a while and then decide to start dragging another and that worked. Now, if I drag one around for a while and then try to drag another it won't let me. But (always a but), if I tap at exactly the same moment on both draggables they will let me drag them both at the same time. I'll update my code to show you what I've done. I think my problem is that my gesturedetector press doesn't trigger fast enough.

Comment: I think thats the best it can do since it takes time to rebuild the ui. You can try combining streambuilder and absorbpainter to make it take less time to update the absorbpainter.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping each container with an Inkwell and adding a boolean would do the trick.

Add a boolean on top of `Widget Build` first:

```
bool isPressed=false;
```

Try this:

```
InkWell(
 onLongPress: () {
   if(isPressed==false){
     setState(() {
      isPressed=true;
     });
     //do something
   }
 }
)
```

You could also wrap it with a GestureDetector. However, there won't be any animation produced every time you click on that container.

```
GestureDetector(
 onLongPress: () {
  if(isPressed==false){
     setState(() {
      isPressed=true;
     });
     //do something
  },
 }
)
```

I would also suggest using a ListView.builder when creating each container instead of manually inputting them one by one. Example:

Generate an array first above the Widget Build method:

```
final items = List<String>.generate(100, (i) => "Item $i");
```

Place this inside your Scaffold's body or inside a Container:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: items.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    return ListTile( //you can change this to a container
      title: Text('${items[index]}'),
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: it doesnt work, I have multiple draggables on the screen at once and I can still drag 2 or more at the same time. I want only to be able to drag 1

Comment: so I tried your solution but I can't seem to get it to work (Thanks for the replies by the way, I really appreciate it!) I posted what I did in the main question.

Comment: @Sniperduel17 Sorry about that, I will check why its still not working.

Comment: It doesn't work since your draggable is a widget. I will fix the code above to solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry @Sniperduel17 I don't know how to solve your problem.